# Remove independent numbers using a PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove independent numbers in a string in PHP using regular expressions?

Examples:

- `"hi123"` should not be modified.
- `"hi 123"` should be converted to `"hi "`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the pattern `\b\d+\b` where `\b` matches a word boundary. Here are some tests:

```
$tests = array(
    'hi123',
    '123hi',
    'hi 123',
    '123'
);
foreach($tests as $test) {
    preg_match('@\b\d+\b@', $test, $match);
    echo sprintf('"%s" -> %s' . "\n", $test, isset($match[0]) ? $match[0] : '(no match)');
}
// "hi123"  -> (no match)
// "123hi"  -> (no match)
// "hi 123" -> 123
// "123"    -> 123
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby (PHP is probably close), I would do it with

```
string_without_numbers = string.gsub(/\b\d+\b/, '')
```

where the part between `//` is the regex and `\b` indicates a word boundary. Note that this would turn `"hi 123 foo"` into `"hi  foo"` (note: there should be two spaces between the words). If words are only separated by spaces, you could choose to use

```
string_without_numbers = string.gsub(/ \d+ /, ' ')
```

which replaces every sequences of digits surrounded by two spaces with a single space. This may leave numbers at the end of a string, which may not be what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/ [0-9]+( |$)/S', ' ', 'hi 123 aaa123 123aaa 234');
```

Comment: This probably won't do the expected thing for input like 'hi 123abc'.

Comment: Now it should be fine i missed some stuff that should be at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/ [0-9]+.+/', ' ', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex : regex='\s\d+'